# Nodejs import fails with syntax error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making use of `react-router` node module for routing in a react app. I am importing required modules as follows.

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var { Route, RouteHandler, Link } = Router;
// ... remaining code ...
```

But I am getting syntax error on line no. 3 i.e. `var { Route, RouteHandler, Link } = Router;`

### Error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing:

```
var {x,y} = {x:3,y:5};
```

Is called a [*destructuring assignment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and is a new feature in JavaScript, it requires a new JavaScript runtime. This feature is not supported in NodeJS yet and not even in v8 yet (the JS engine JavaScript runs on). You can either assign it in 3 lines manually or use a tool like [Traceur](https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/demo/repl.html#var%20%7Bx%2Cy%7D%20%3D%20%7Bx%3A3%2Cy%3A5%7D) or [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl.html#?code=var%20%7Bx%2Cy%7D%20%3D%20%7Bx%3A3%2C%20y%3A5%7D&experimental=true&playground=true&evaluate=true) to compile your ES6 (new specification of EcmaScript) to ES5 (what node runs) code.

Comment: 6to5 also has a `require` hook if I remember correctly.